# HTML/CSS create body wider than viewport

Tags: html, css, viewport, document-body

I'll trying to create website with horizontal scrolling.
But when I set element wider than viewport - body is do not wider.

Following code doesn't works

```
body {
    float: left
}
```

How I can do body wider than viewport?

I create fiddle for this - https://jsfiddle.net/stas_webdev/9L1gLoww/

Update: I have a unknown num of .grid-cell blocks, in theory. So, I don't know, how wide should be body width in each case. It should be flexible.

Comment: You need to make width of the body more than 100%. 100% will take the screen/window width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have unknown number of cells then just add overflow property on your html, body. see below:

```
html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your body wider, you can set its width attribute to something bigger than your viewport's width. For example:

```
body { width: 150%; }
```

This will take your viewport's width and make the body's width 50% bigger.

Comment: I have a unknown num of .grid-cell blocks, in theory. So, I don't know, how wide should be body width in each case. It should be flexible. So, this solution will not work :(